# Change the length of the Android Alarm

Tags: android, clock, alarm, android-alarms

The android alarm duration is basically at 1min (I think).
I would like to change it, so I can set the length/the duration at 4min for exemple (the duration of a song).

Can you tell me which methods I can call to change it ?

Can you guide me please ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use AlarmManager for this. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

It has setRepeating method where you can set the interval you want (the second parameter is time in milliseconds that the alarm should first go off).